# Inherited model many2one picking a wrong field value

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I am trying to reference form_serial_no field of formdownload model in my inherited  model(plot.allocate). Instead of the dropdown to show the computed value of form_serial_no which is company_short_code padded with sequence e.g CCK0000006, it's showing "CCK" which is the value of company_short_code excluding the sequence. In actual fact, it's referencing company_short_code of companyname model instead of the computed value of form_serial_no of formdownload model. And in the database, form_serial_no field is showing the right record which is something like these......ABC0000008, CDG0000003 and so on. This is my question, is there any reason why form_serial_no_id Many2one field of plot.allocate model is not picking the value of form_serial_no Char field of formdownload, instead, it's picking the company_short_code Char field of companyname model?

Secondly, how can i change the status field default value of companyname model record to true when a value is picked in form_serial_no_id Many2one field of plot.allocate model?

Kindly help me look into these.

Below are my code snippet

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp import models, fields, api

class CompanyName(models.Model):
    _name = 'companyname'
    _rec_name = 'company_short_code'

    company_name = fields.Char(string="Company Name", required=True)
    company_short_code = fields.Char(string="Company short code", required=True)

class FormDownload(models.Model):
    _name = 'formdownload'
    _rec_name = 'form_serial_no'

    name = fields.Many2one('companyname', string="Company Name", ondelete='cascade',
                                      required=True)
    form_serial_no = fields.Char(string="Form Serial No", readonly=True)
    status = fields.Boolean(string="Status", default=False)

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):

        serial_no = self.env['ir.sequence'].get('formdownload.form_serial_no')
        code = self.env['companyname'].browse(vals['name']).company_short_code

        # capitalize company short code values
        code = code.upper()

        # merge code and serial number
        vals['form_serial_no'] = code + serial_no
        return super(FormDownload, self).create(vals)

class PlotAllocation(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'plot.allocate'

    form_serial_no_id = fields.Many2one('formdownload',
                                        domain=[('status', '=', False)],
                                         ondelete='cascade', string="Form Serial No")

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        record = self.env['formdownload'].search([('name', 'like', vals.get('name', False))]).form_serial_no
        status = self.env['companyname'].search([('name', 'like', vals.get('name', False))]).status
        if vals.get('form_serial_no_id') == record.id:
            self.env['companyname'].write({status : True})

            return super(PlotAllocation, self).create(vals)
```

Comment: when you create a record you don't have any error like Keyerror : name ? because you are asking if vals contain `name`

Comment: no, i did not have keyerror.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the view the many2one is always showing the value of the field specified in the Model class by `_rec_name` :

by default `_rec_name = 'name'`

so in reality your model is like this :

```py
 class FormDownload(models.Model):
        _name = 'formdownload'
        _rec_name = 'name'
```

so he will retreive the value of field `name` name is also a many2one so the value retrieved is the `_rec_name` of model `companyname` with is `company_short_code`:

so i you want to change the value of many2one you have to choice:

if one field  is enough than specify the `_rec_name = 'form_serial_no'`

if you want to combined value like first && last name then override name_get method

```py
@api.multi
def name_get(self):
    """
        change the displayed value on m2o
    """
    result = []
    for record in self:
        result.append((record.id, _(" %s  %s") % (record.first_name, record.last_name)))
    return result
```

**EDITS**

in create method is easy just remove all the code in create method and put this two line

```py
rec_id = super(PlotAllocation, self).create(vals)
# create return a record you can acces it's value 
rec_id.form_serial_no_id.name.status = True
return rec_id # you need to return the record
```

Comment: let me know if you didn't understand what i'm saying

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's really helpful.........I was able to solve the first question with this response........Now, the second question?

Comment: so status by default is false when you select a value in you m2o field you want the companyname related to this record to have status = true.
what you mean by true if there is at least one record selected from that company status = true? and at least up vote for solving you first question and for information i spend more than 5 minute for it.

Comment: nothing happened but what you asking well need some time you need to override create && write of the last method or create one2many relation in you first model to compute the value of status. try to work on it if you could not put your code that you tryied and we will help you

Comment: doing that already, i will get back to you in few minutes time. Thanks for your responses, i really appreciate it.

Comment: This is the override method......but it's not changing the status field value @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        record = self.env['formdownload'].browse(vals['name']).form_serial_no
        status = self.env['companyname'].browse(vals['name']).status
        if vals['form_serial_no_id'] in record :
            self.env['companyname'].write({status : True})
            
            return super(PlotAllocation, self).create(vals)

Comment: use search `record = self.env['formdownload'].search([('name', 'like' , vals.get('name', False))].form_serial_no`

Comment: and vals m2o is integer : `if vals.get('form_serial_no_id') == record.id :` still there is no upvote lol

Comment: i have up voted, the reason it's not showing is because my reputation is not up to 15 yet...............back to the issue, it's still not changing the status field value to true.

Comment: edit your question remove uneeded code ant put you method

Comment: I dont understand?

Comment: edit your question and put the code of the method so i can help you

Comment: check my edit for create the problem now is with write or unlink i think you should use compute field it's better.

Comment: i followed your advice, but nothing changes